# ADFS as a Service Provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, provider, claims, trust

I have found plenty of information about how to configure ADFS as a service provider, many documents online, however, my configuration interface in ADFS looks nothing like the screenshots I am seeing in the configuration docs.  For instance, to configure ADFS claims provider trust for accepting SAML you need the following screen to configure it.  Below you can see there is a way to "Choose Profile" which clearly has the ability to accept SAML 2.0 assertion, and it's easy to configure, this screen is in all the docs I have looked at (See below).

[image]

So when I try to do this at my own ADFS instance this configuration is not available.  See below, you can clearly see "Choose Profile" navigation option is not available as it is in all the configuration docs I have found online, I have looked high and low for any documentation that would tell me if I need some extra licensing to get this option, I have found nothing:

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to get this option to display in my ADFS instance?  I am currently on windows server 2016 standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have installed ADFS v1.x rather than ADFS 2.0 or upwards.

SAML 2.0 was not available in ADFS 1.x.

There is no extra licensing for this.

Comment: Forgive me, I am somewhat new to ADFS configuration, but I believe adfs 1.0 required IIS to run, and I don't have IIS running currently and ADFS is working as expected for all other features aside from the one in the question.  Could it be something else.  Below is the Product Version I got from Powershell: 10.0.14393.0.   I ran the following command to get the version: (Get-Item C:\Windows\ADFS\Microsoft.IdentityServer.ServiceHost.exe).VersionInfo.ProductVersion

Comment: You might be correct somehow, but remember I installed this from a Server Role, and I don't see any way to upgrade the server to another version even if this was the issue.  Any suggestions would be great.  I also wanted to add that I am configured for SAML 2.0 as a Relying Party Trust, so the ADFS server supports SAML 2.0 Outbound, just not  inbound.